# Combining Two Observable Sequences

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I recently got back into programming with RX and came up with a problem combining two sequences.

I've got sequence **o1** which looks like this:

```
var o1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7))
                   .Select(i => i + 2)
                   .Take(2)
                   .StartWith(1);
```

And I have sequence **o2** which looks like this:

```
var o2 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
                   .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                   .Select(i => i + 2)
                   .Take(4)
                   .StartWith(1);
```

That roughly corresponds to this marble diagram:

```
o1: 1 - - - - - - 2 - - - - - - 3 -
o2: - a - - b - - c - - d - - e - -
o3: - 1a- - - - - 2c- - - - - - 3e-
```

I'm just looking for sequence **o3** but I can't seem to work it out. Neither `Zip` nor `CombineLatest` on their own are up to the job.

Comment: Is it "okay" that `o2` is saving the last value via a `Subscribe()` into an ordinary variable/field/property? Or must it be one combined observable?

Comment: I'd prefer a combined observable.

Comment: Are you searching for the [`WithLatestFrom`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/9d84ce4cb43d286597134fb7f1e87c28daa89e6d/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable.Multiple.cs#L969) operator?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias that's exactly what I was looking for. If you're interested in adding it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably searching for the [`WithLatestFrom`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/9d84ce4cb43d286597134fb7f1e87c28daa89e6d/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable.Multiple.cs#L969) operator.

> Merges two observable sequences into one observable sequence by combining each element from the first source with the latest element from the second source, if any. Starting from Rx.NET 4.0, this will subscribe to second before subscribing to first, to have a latest element readily available in case first emits an element right away.

In its simplest form it has this signature:

```
public static IObservable<(TFirst First, TSecond Second)> WithLatestFrom<TFirst, TSecond>(
    this IObservable<TFirst> first, IObservable<TSecond> second);
```

The resulting sequence emits elements of type [`ValueTuple<TFirst,TSecond>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2).

Comment: This does produce `1a`, `2b`, and finally `3e` - not exactly what the OP was after.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, I've noticed. The values `2` and `c` are emitted roughly the same time, so there is a race condition between observing `2b` or `2c`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `CombineLatest()`, `Buffer()`, `Where()` and `Select()` to build the observable `o3`:

- `CombineLatest()` - Simply combine the two observables `o1` and `o2` to any data structure you want (I used a `Tuple`).
- `Buffer(2,1)` - Build a "sliding window" to see the previous and current `Tuple`.
- `Where()` - Filter the "sliding window", that you only get a sliding window where the first element (from `o1`) of the previous `Tuple` is different to the first element (again from `o1`) of the current `Tuple`, so you know there was a change, regardless of what `o2` is doing in the meantime.
- `Select()` - Simply select the current (or previous) `Tuple`.

The observable might look like this:

```
var o1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7))
       .Select(i => i + 2)
       .Take(2)
       .StartWith(1)
       .Do(it => {
           Console.WriteLine("-- o1 triggered: "+it);
       });
var o2 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
       .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
       .Select(i => i + 2)
       .Take(4)
       .StartWith(1)
       .Do(it => {
           Console.WriteLine("-- o2 triggered: "+it);
       });
o1.CombineLatest(o2, Tuple.Create)
    .StartWith(Tuple.Create(0L, 0L))
    .Buffer(2, 1)
    .Do(it => {
        Console.WriteLine("-- After Buffer: "+String.Join(",",it));
    })
    .Where(it => {
        if (it.Count != 2) {
            return false;
        }
        return it[0].Item1 != it[1].Item1;
    })
    .Select(it => it[1])
    .Subscribe(it => {
        Console.WriteLine("Final: "+it);
    });
```

This will generate the following output:

```
-- o1 triggered: 1
-- o2 triggered: 1
-- After Buffer: (0, 0),(1, 1)
Final: (1, 1)
-- o2 triggered: 2
-- After Buffer: (1, 1),(1, 2)
-- o1 triggered: 2
-- After Buffer: (1, 2),(2, 2)
Final: (2, 2)
-- o2 triggered: 3
-- After Buffer: (2, 2),(2, 3)
-- o2 triggered: 4
-- After Buffer: (2, 3),(2, 4)
-- o2 triggered: 5
-- After Buffer: (2, 4),(2, 5)
-- o1 triggered: 3
-- After Buffer: (2, 5),(3, 5)
Final: (3, 5)
-- After Buffer: (3, 5)
```

You might need to adjust/add/remove the `StartWith()` calls depending on your actual requirement and/or change the `Select()` call to get the previous or current `Tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected for the two example source observables:

```
IObservable<long>  o1 =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7))
        .Select(i => i + 2)
        .Take(2)
        .StartWith(1);

IObservable<char> o2 =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Select(i => i + 2)
        .Take(4)
        .StartWith(1)
        .Select(x => (char)('a' + x - 1));

IObservable<string> o3 =
    from x1 in o1
    join x2 in o2
        on Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0))
        equals Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0))
    select $"{x1}{x2}";

o3.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

The output I get is:

```
1a
2c
3e
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.